# Make locator.updatedb run daily on Snow Leopard w/o hacking /System/Library?

Tags: launchd, command-line

On Snow Leopard, the `locate` database is updated once a week by a launchd job, `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist`. I'd like to make the updater run daily, but AFAIK it's considered very bad form to edit anything in `/System`.

What's the best way to change its `StartCalendarInterval` so it runs once a day?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I understand it, that System folder launchd job does nothing but execute `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` itself.

So simply [create your own launchd job](http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=20050620071558293) executing `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` that runs once a day.

As a sidenote, [here's a Super User answer](https://superuser.com/questions/161183/cannot-manually-update-database-for-locate/161558#161558) which recommends using `mdfind -name <filename>` instead of `locate` so that you can use the Spotlight database which is continually updated.

And this [Ask Different answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/820/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-tutorial-for-writing-from-scratch-a-cron-style-laun) has more info on creating launchd jobs if you need more help with that.

Comment: +1 for creating a custom launchd job. iCal could schedule it - but that's an extra level of abstraction. Lingon is awesome if you don't like writing plist files by hand. http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lingon/id411211026?mt=12

Comment: @bmike Thanks for the Lingon link. I had a vague memory of that no longer being developed, nice to see the developer is now selling it on the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with 'locate' and with Spotlight is that it doesn't search every file. It used to be possible to work-around this by updating the updatedb as root, which would warn you that was a potential security hole (i.e. anyone with read access to the database could get a list of every file in any user's $HOME) but since most Mac users are the only user on their computers, that was not a huge concern.

I finally got so fed up that I wrote my own script which will:

- make a plain-text index of every file, link, and directory
- search that index using `egrep`
- offer to restrict searches to $HOME or the current directory if certain arguments are given
- if nothing is found in the index, offer to update the index, or search with `mdfind`

You can [download the script here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18414/bin/loc?dl=1) [Dropbox link]. It should be fairly easy to understand how it works just by reading through it.